# Removed left recursion from grammar, but now the grammar allows invalid derivations

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to remove the left recursion from a grammar, however after following an algorithm to do so I now believe the grammar I've produced allows for the derivation of statements that aren't valid.

A part of the grammar is as follows:

A -> **a** A **b** A **c** A **d**

A -> **e** A

A -> f

A -> A + A

A -> A * A

So from my understanding, the bottom two productions are direct left recursion and the way to remove the left recursion is by introducing a new nonterminal A', however I then get this:

A -> **a** A **b** A **c** A **d** A'

A -> **e** A A'

A -> f A'

A' -> + A A'

A' -> * A A'

A' -> epsilon

Yet this allows the derivation of **a** A **b** A **c** A **d** * f

Which would not be a valid derivation with the original grammar. Can please someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `a A b A c A d * f` is totally valid in the original. `A` -> `A * A` -> `a A b A c A d * A` (expand left A) -> `a A b A c A d * f` (expand right A).

Comment: So it is, I've obviously not considered this closely enough. Thank you for your help. If you want to answer the question, I'll mark your answer as correct so I can close this.